# Alternative/mirror site for HP drivers

Tags: drivers, mirror-site

I'm not able to download any printer driver from the HP site. Is there an alternative or mirror site where drivers are just archived or cached?

Comment: The HP site makes me lose hair.

Comment: 14 years ago, someone by the name of Toro asked this question and tried to pave the way, hopeful that HP would listen and change. Alas, on this Halloween night of 2023, I needed to print and found no help on the HP website and even discovered they discontinued the driver I needed.

Comment: Gladly, I found an old .pkg file that said "this update requires Mac OS 12 or older". I used ```pkgutil --expand-full HewlettPackardPrinterDrivers.pkg HPFolder``` to extract another .pkg file that was browsable (right click + show package contents). Files in the "Payload" folder can be placed in the folders of the same name on the system and the driver will then be "manually" installed. HP Deskjet F2140 (F2100 all-in-one series) now prints. F* HP and planned obsolescence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd think that a multi-billion dollar corporation like HP would have reliable update servers.  Unfortunately, that is not the case.  HP has the absolute worst update architecture of any manufacturer on the planet.

Comment: I'm trying to download a simple printer driver, and it's giving me 942 BYTES/sec.. that's right, 0.9 KILO bytes.. unbelievable!

Comment: +1 - Support page wont work in chrome, only sometimes works in firefox (I refuse to use IE). Downloads from a single ftp server - no mirrors, and large downloads fail most of the time. Especially annoying to get laptop graphics drivers because HP also used customization which mean you can not use generic drivers from AMD/Nvidia

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [www.driverguide.com](http://www.driverguide.com) since the late 90's. There's a lot of fluff on there, but a lot of useful content too.

Comment: No, it belongs here just as much as SU. As an admin I run into this problem constantly, especially with HP.

Comment: haha I realise I'm doing the thing I hate the most, which is when people vote for something to go to SU just because it says "printer" instead of "networked printer". Point taken, I'll edit my statement.

Answer (score 0):

**sTILL** **NO LINK** TO AN alternate HP DRIVER Downloads. I did however find the link below for a paid for service which will keep All your drivers updated but costs a small fortune :(
http://www.tweakbit.com/land/driver-updater/support/?[content=ppcduprinter&build=ppc1&exit=false&instructions=1&kw=HP&gclid=CjwKEAjw6_q5BRCOp-Hj-IfHwncSJABMtDaifGXoKEA11nPADYxRvap_M8Bho5hLXqdII7sE9PusDBoCnwrw_wcB](http://www.tweakbit.com/land/driver-updater/support/?content=ppcduprinter&build=ppc1&exit=false&instructions=1&kw=HP&gclid=CjwKEAjw6_q5BRCOp-Hj-IfHwncSJABMtDaifGXoKEA11nPADYxRvap_M8Bho5hLXqdII7sE9PusDBoCnwrw_wcB)

Comment: What about the link in the other answer?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that HP support sites for other locales may sometimes work when the US site is down.
https://www.support.hp.com/za-en/drivers